# echo map reduce output in shell script using oozie

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, oozie

The .sh script has the following content inside it

```
echo hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter TABLE_NAME
```

The above script will be called by oozie which will capture whatever output the above command emits. The problem is, the above command is executed and no output gets echoed since all the output is happening in the background. How to capture those background output and echo it using shell script?

Comment: 1. Save it to a file. 2. Wait until it finishes. 3. Output the file. ..

Comment: I think this is an oozie question, not a bash question. Your script is almost certainly producing the output, what matters is how to capture that output in oozie, i.e., how oozie calls this script.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you need to have `<capture-output/>` in the Oozie Shell action.

Also to capture the output in Oozie shell action, the script need to be something like the following:

```
set var=`hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter TABLE_NAME`
echo "capture_var=$var"
```

After you do this, the variable will be available to be passed/used within Oozie using:
`${wf:actionData('shellscriptoozieactionname')['capture_var']}`